# How do I solve 8 variable and 8 equations linear system in python?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra

I want to verify my calculation using python but I have no clue how to solve this system when variables are also present on the right side of the equation. I trying to solve the following equation:[K][u] = [f]
where:

```
K = (10**-7)*np.array([[ 5.21250000e-01,  2.04471348e-17, -5.21250000e-01,
         4.17000000e-01, -5.21250000e-01, -5.55111512e-17,
         5.21250000e-01, -4.17000000e-01],
       [ 2.04471348e-17,  2.08500000e-01,  8.34000000e-01,
        -2.08500000e-01, -8.32667268e-17, -2.08500000e-01,
        -8.34000000e-01,  2.08500000e-01],
       [-5.21250000e-01,  8.34000000e-01,  3.85725000e+00,
        -1.25100000e+00,  5.21250000e-01, -8.34000000e-01,
        -3.85725000e+00,  1.25100000e+00],
       [ 4.17000000e-01, -2.08500000e-01, -1.25100000e+00,
         8.54850000e+00, -4.17000000e-01,  2.08500000e-01,
         1.25100000e+00, -8.54850000e+00],
       [-5.21250000e-01, -1.11022302e-16,  5.21250000e-01,
        -4.17000000e-01,  4.89975000e+00, -1.25100000e+00,
        -4.89975000e+00,  1.66800000e+00],
       [-6.93889390e-17, -2.08500000e-01, -8.34000000e-01,
         2.08500000e-01, -1.25100000e+00,  8.96550000e+00,
         2.08500000e+00, -8.96550000e+00],
       [ 5.21250000e-01, -8.34000000e-01, -3.85725000e+00,
         1.25100000e+00, -4.89975000e+00,  2.08500000e+00,
         8.23575000e+00, -2.50200000e+00],
       [-4.17000000e-01,  2.08500000e-01,  1.25100000e+00,
        -8.54850000e+00,  1.66800000e+00, -8.96550000e+00,
        -2.50200000e+00,  1.73055000e+01]])

u.T = np.array([0, 0, 0, u_2y, 0, u_3y, 0, 0])

f.T = np.array([r1x, r1y, r2x, 0, r3x, -15, r4x, r4y-15])
```

I am trying to solve for u_2y, u_3y, r1x, r1y, r2x, r3x, r4x, r4y. So far, I haven't seen any examples in which there are variables on the right side so I am a little confused on how to solve this problem using sicpy.linalg.solve.

Answer (score 2):

In a more general way, your problem can be formulated

*A x = B x + c ⇒ (A-B) x = c*

but, if you write the 8 equations, you will notice that in two equations you have ONLY the two *fundamental* unknowns, no dependency on the remaining 6 unknowns, so you can immediately solve these 2 equations, next you notice that each of the remaining 6 unknowns appears in only one equation, so if you substitute the two fundamental **ex**-unknowns you are directly computing the remaining unknowns.

Let's work out a simpler example…

```
a11 a12 a13   x1   b1
a21 a22 a23 · x2 = b2
a31 a32 a33   00   b3+x3
```

From the first two equations you have
*{x1, x2} = inv([a11 a12;a21 a22])·{b1 b2}*
so now *x1* and *x2* are known and you can substitute in the last equation
*x3 = a31·x1 + a32·x2 - b3.*